# C language-C 90-printing many copies of a square next to each other

Tags: c

I have created a program which prints a square of specific dimensions and uses a particular character,based on user's input.My goal is to print multiple copies of this shape(the user will determine the number of copies each time),each next to each other.I tried using a for loop in main,but the copies are printed vertically.I also thought of printing the first line of the shape,the second one etc, but I don't know how to apply this to my code.
Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getsize(void);
char get_char(void);
void printsquare(int size,char ch);

int main(){
    int size;
    char ch;

    size=getsize();
    ch=get_char();
    printsquare(size,ch);

}
int getsize(void){
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of selected shape: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    return size ;
}

char get_char(void){
    char character;
    printf("Enter the character of selected shape: ");
    scanf("\n%c",&character);
    return character;
}

void printsquare(int size,char ch){
    int i,j;
    for (i=1;i<=size;i++){
        for (j=1;j<i;j++){
            printf("-");

        }
        if (i==1 || i==size){
            for (j=1;j<=size;j++){
                printf("%c",ch);
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("%c",ch);
            for (j=1;j<=size-2;j++){
                printf("-");
            }
            printf("%c",ch);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: You need to print all the first lines, then all the second lines, then all the third lines, and so on.

Comment: That first nested `for` loop (`for (j=1;j<i;j++)`) causes the output to be diagonal - is this intentional?

Comment: Yes.It is supposed to be diagonal like that.

Comment: Alternative: Allocate a 2D "surface" and create drawing functions to paint in it. When done, just print the surface and `free` it.

Comment: @Barmar How can i apply this in my code??

Comment: @Jim Figure it out yourself, that's how you learn.

Answer (score 0):

remember always try think simple, the following code show how must `printsquare` must be

```
void printsquare(int size,char ch){
    int i;
    int j;
    // print first line
    for (i= 0; i < size; i++) {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    // print inner line
    for (i= 0; i < size; i++) {
        putchar(ch);
        for (j = 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
            putchar('-');
        }
        putchar(ch);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    // print last line
    // print first line
    for (i= 0; i < size; i++) {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

another implementation

```
void printsquare(int size,char ch){
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i= 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == size - 1) {
            // print last and first line
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                putchar(ch);
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else {
            // print inner lines
            putchar(ch);
            for (j = 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
                putchar('-');
            }
            putchar(ch);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

now for multiple copies

```
void printsquare(int size,char ch, int copies){
    int i;
    int j;
    int c;
    for (i= 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == size - 1) {
            for (c = 0; c < copies; c++) {
                // print last and first line
                for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    putchar(ch);
                }
                putchar(' ');
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else {
            for (c = 0; c < copies; c++) {
                // print inner lines
                putchar(ch);
                for (j = 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
                    putchar('-');
                }
                putchar(ch);
                putchar(' ');
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read the entirety of the question. The existing code works as intended - the question is about getting multiple shapes printing side-by-side.

Comment: thanks for comment, i'll add example for multiple copies side by side, but main question didn't print square shape in right format

Comment: We clarified in the comments above that the diagonal nature of the output was intended.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to repeat the entire printing logic of each line as many times as you need.

```
void printsquare(int size,char ch, int reps) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=1;i<=size;i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < reps; k++) {
            for (j=1;j<i;j++){
                printf("-");

            }
            if (i==1 || i==size){
                for (j=1;j<=size;j++){
                    printf("%c",ch);
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("%c",ch);
                for (j=1;j<=size-2;j++){
                    printf("-");
                }
                printf("%c",ch);
            }

            putchar(' ');
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return ;
}
```

I have added a space to differentiate the shapes, but it could be another dash, or nothing at all.

`printsquare(4, '@', 2)` gives the `stdout`:

```
@@@@ @@@@ 
-@--@ -@--@ 
--@--@ --@--@ 
---@@@@ ---@@@@
```